How to import an image during the +page.js load() function?
I am trying to build a blog with Svelte, my folder structure is as follow:

posts:

slug1:

banner.webp
content.md


...


src:

blog:

+page.svelte
+page.server.ts
[slug]:

+page.svelte
+page.server.ts







In the src/blog/[slug]/+page.server.ts I have the following code:
import { getPostMetadata, getPostBannerImageURL } from "$lib/blog"
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types';

export const prerender = true;

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ params }) => {
    return {
        slug: params.slug,
        metadata: getPostMetadata(params.slug),
        bannerURL: // Code I am trying to figure out
    };
};

I want my code to be Server-Side Rendered and also I want to be able to statically compile it. I would like to add the banner image (/posts/${params.slug}/banner.webp) to the optimized asset of Vite and get the right URL to then be able to display.
I tried to dynamically import the image but it doesn't work:
bannerURL: await import(`../../../posts/${params.slug}/banner.webp`)

I have the following error:
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at String (<anonymous>)
    at escape_html (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index.js:30:15)
    at _page (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/blog/_slug_/_page.svelte.js:8:416)
    at children (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js:1155:9)
    at _layout (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/entries/pages/_layout.svelte.js:202:3)
    at Root (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js:1150:5)
    at render (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/index.js:99:3)
    at Function._render [as render] (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/chunks/internal.js:1112:20)
    at render_response (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:1800:34)
    at async render_page (file:///Users/jlagesse/Documents/GitHub/adrien-lagesse.io/.svelte-kit/output/server/index.js:2627:12)


How does the import not work?

If I use: bannerURL: await import(../../../posts/${params.slug}/banner.webp) I have the following error: TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Dynamic imports include the entire module, my suspicion is that the error is a side effect of expecting something different from what is actually returned by the load function.
You probably need to get the default export:
await import(`../../../posts/${params.slug}/banner.webp`).then(m => m.default)

There appears to be a bug in the relative path mapping that may prevent this from working, in that case a glob import can be used manually (Vite tries to do this automatically under the hood with a regular dynamic import that contains parameters).
const images = import.meta.glob(
  '../../../posts/*/banner.webp',
  { eager: true, import: 'default' },
);

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ params }) => {
    return {
        // ...
        bannerURL: images[`../../../posts/${params.slug}/banner.webp`],
    };
};


Thank you, this solved the error I was getting, however, it did not solve the problem I had. I had to use import.meta.glob("/posts/*/banner.webp")  for vite to process my images.

There appear to be bugs in Vite regarding the relative path resolution, so maybe the glob approach is necessary right now given certain directory structures...

I updated my answer to include that approach as well.
